# Presto SQL multiple conditions not working

Tags: sql, presto

I am writing a simple query trying to get all records in the 12 months interval from now and in the US country.

This is my query:

```
select * from table
where (created >=  (cast(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')as timestamp) - interval '12' month))
and country = 'United States'
```

However, this query runs forever and results in an error "Error fetching results".

I am not getting an error if I remove `- interval '12'` part. Is there a way so that I could specify both conditions?

Comment: Sounds like a memory error because of a huge amount of result rows. Please replace `select *` with `select count(*)` and tell us the result.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have tested it with a smaller table and it worked. It was indeed a memory error. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that `cast(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')as timestamp)` seems to be just cumbersome version of `current_date` which should do the same trick here.